# Doctrine - database relation - many-to-many add status

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, many-to-many, relational

How do I implement the following scenario the best way in ORM (Doctrine)?

Scenario:
A user can belong to one or many teams. 
A team can consist of one or many users.

So, the first part is no problem, but I want the user to have an "activation_status" **for every team he belongs**.

So as I'm coming from SQL and relational databases i could add an "activation_status" field in my many-to-many relationship table "team2user"

-> database fields: team_id, user_id, activation_status

But how can I implement that with Doctrine? I persist the entities team and user. 
But how do I persist the activation_status correctly?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I will add new entity "activation", because it seems best solution in my case. But adding a TeamUser entity would be an alternative way to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could revise your entities and add an Activation Entity, that way your entities would be like this:

1. User has several Activations (OneToMany)
2. Activation belongs to one user (ManyToOne), and belongs to a Team (ManyToOne)
3. Team has several Activations (OneToMany)

You can also define ManyToMany relationship between User and Team through Activation entity.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to achieve this (at least up to Doctrine 2.1, I'm not 100% sure how it looks in higher versions) is create separate entity `TeamUser` and relate it with `User` and `Team` entities using `ManyToOne` relation. Then you can put whatever you want inside your new entity (for your example it will be additional `$activationStatus` property)